# Wordpress - List only links to existing Image sizes in a post

Tags: wordpress, image, frontend, download

I´m using the following piece of code to offer download links to the images of a post, that are included in the media library.

```
 <?php
                    $images = array();
                    $image_sizes = array ('superlarge', 'large', 'medium', 'small');
                    $img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );

                    if ( $img_id ) {
                            echo 'Image Download: ';
                            foreach( $image_sizes as $image_size ) {
                                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, $image_size );
                                    $name =  '' . $image[1] . 'x' . $image[2] . '';
                                    $images[] = '<a href="' . $image[0] . '" target="_blank">' . $name . '</a>';
                            }
                            echo implode( ' | ', $images );
                    } ?>
```

This works fine if there is an image with "superlarge" dimensions. In that case I get a list of the 4 images sizes, with download link like this:

"superlarge, large, medium, small"

The problem is, that it doesn´t work properly if there is only the "large" image size. In that case I get a list like this:

"**large, large,** medium, small"

Is there a a way to show the download link, only if the size of the image exists? In that case this would be : "large, medium, small"

Thanks in advance for any help that solves that issue

Comment: I'm not seeing 'superlarge' as a media size https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Media_Screen Have you added a plugin to cater for 'superlarge'?

Comment: "Superlarge" is only an example for "any other download size". I added some more image sizes with "add_image_size" in my functions.php.